# Customised command prompt is not saving chages after re-opening it

Tags: unix, path, ps1

I am trying to use PS1 to customise my command prompt in mac, but the changes are not saved, when I try to re-open the terminal.

I have edited the .bashrc file, and the changes are effective only for that session. If I close and re-open the terminal, all saved changes are lost.

Below is the .bashrc file that i have edited.

```
export PS1="\u@\h \d \@ \w >"
export PATH="/Users/avbanerj/test_script1:$PATH"
```

Could you please tell me what shall I add in my .bashrc or .profile so that changes are reflected everytime I open the terminal?

Comment: Check if .bashrc file run automatically. You can use instead .profile file.

Answer (score 0):

This is from `info bash`.
-Erik

```
6.2 Bash Startup Files
======================

This section describes how Bash executes its startup files.  If any of
the files exist but cannot be read, Bash reports an error.  Tildes are
expanded in filenames as described above under Tilde Expansion (*note
Tilde Expansion::).

   Interactive shells are described in *note Interactive Shells::.

Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with '--login'
........................................................

When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
non-interactive shell with the '--login' option, it first reads and
executes commands from the file '/etc/profile', if that file exists.
After reading that file, it looks for '~/.bash_profile',
'~/.bash_login', and '~/.profile', in that order, and reads and executes
commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The
'--noprofile' option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit
this behavior.

   When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login
shell executes the 'exit' builtin command, Bash reads and executes
commands from the file '~/.bash_logout', if it exists.

Invoked as an interactive non-login shell
.........................................

When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash
reads and executes commands from '~/.bashrc', if that file exists.  This
may be inhibited by using the '--norc' option.  The '--rcfile FILE'
option will force Bash to read and execute commands from FILE instead of
'~/.bashrc'.

   So, typically, your '~/.bash_profile' contains the line
     if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
after (or before) any login-specific initializations.
```